# How to cd to working directory in Xcode Run Script?

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, xcode6

I am attempting to add Parse.com crash reporting to my application, but ran into an issue that I can't seem to find a fix to. [Their documentation](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#analytics/crashreporting/ios/existing) states you should setup a Run Script with the following script:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
cd (path to working directory i.e. - /Users/Username/Documents/ParseProject/parse)

parse symbols "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"
```

The issue I have with this is that it requires an explicit project directory to cd to. That results in obvious problems when using git and attempting to run the same script on another computer.

I have tried changing the cd to a few different options:

```
cd ${PROJECT_DIR}
cd "$PROJECT_DIR"
cd ./ParseProject/parse
cd ./parse
```

How can I get this to work so that it'll function across different computers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I managed to get it to work and was very close before. I had to call `cd "$PROJECT_DIR"/parse`, which now makes sense in hindsight.

The final Run Script for ParseCrashReporting that I'm using is now this:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
cd "$PROJECT_DIR"/parse

parse symbols "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"
```